# Fitting a segmented regression with two zero boundary constraints

Tags: r, regression, lm, constrained-regression, piecewise-linear

I am having trouble with this segmented regression as it requires two constraints and so far I have only treated single constraints.

Here is an example of some data I am trying to fit:

```
library(segmented)
library("readxl")
library(ggplot2)

#DATA PRE-PROCESSING
yields <- c(-0.131, 0.533, -0.397, -0.429, -0.593, -0.778, -0.92, -0.987, -1.113,       -1.314, -0.808, -1.534, -1.377, -1.459, -1.818, -1.686, -1.73, -1.221, -1.595, -1.568, -1.883, -1.53, -1.64, -1.396, -1.679, -1.782, -1.033, -0.539, -1.207, -1.437, -1.521, -0.691, -0.879, -0.974, -1.816, -1.854, -1.752, -1.61, -0.602, -1.364, -1.303, -1.186, -1.336)
maturities <- c(2.824657534246575, 2.9013698630136986, 3.106849315068493, 3.1534246575342464, 3.235616438356164, 3.358904109589041, 3.610958904109589, 3.654794520547945, 3.778082191780822, 3.824657534246575, 3.9013698630136986, 3.9863013698630136, 4.153424657534247, 4.273972602739726, 4.32054794520548, 4.654794520547945, 4.778082191780822, 4.986301369863014, 5.153424657534247, 5.32054794520548, 5.443835616438356, 5.572602739726028, 5.654794520547945, 5.824425480949174, 5.941911819746988, 6.275245153080321, 6.4063926940639275, 6.655026573845348, 6.863013698630137, 7.191780821917808, 7.32054794520548, 7.572602739726028, 7.693150684931507, 7.901369863013699, 7.986301369863014, 8.32054794520548, 8.654794520547945, 8.986301369863014, 9.068493150684931, 9.32054794520548, 9.654794520547945, 9.903660453626769, 10.155026573845348)

 off_2 <- 2.693277939965566
 off_10 <- 10.655026573845348

 bond_data = data.frame(yield_change = yields, maturity = maturities) code here
```

I am trying to fit a segmented model (with a formula of "yield_change~maturity") that has the following constraints:

1. At maturity = 2 I want the yield_change to be zero
2. At maturity = 10, I want the yield_change to zero
3. I want breakpoints(fixed in x) at the 3, 5 and 7-year maturity values.
4. The off_2 and off_10 variables are the offsets I must use (to set the yields to zero at the 2 and 10-year mark)

As I mentioned before, my previous regressions only required one initial constraint, having one offset value I had to use, I did the following:

1. I subtracted the offset value from the maturity vector (for example I had maturity = c(10.8,10.9,11,14,16,18, etc... then subtracted the offset, always lower than the initial vector value, 10,4 for example and then fitted a lm with an origin constraint)
2. From there I could use the segmented package and fit as many breakpoints as I wanted)
3. As the segmented() function requires a lm object as an input that was possible.

However in this case I cannot to the previous approach as I have two offsets and cannot subtract all the values by off_2 or off_10 as it would fix one point at the zero and not the other.

What I have tried doing is the following:

Separate the dataset into maturities below 5 and maturities over 5 (and essentially apply a segmented model to each of these (with only one breakpoint being 3 or 7).

The issue is that I need to have the 5 year point yield the same for the two models.

I have done this:

```
bond_data_sub5 <- bond_data[bond_data$maturity < 5,]
bond_data_over5 <- bond_data[bond_data$maturity > 5,]

bond_data_sub5["maturity"] <- bond_data_sub5$maturity - off_2

#2 to 5 year model
model_sub5 <- lm(yield_change~maturity+0, data = bond_data_sub5)

plot(bond_data_sub5$maturity,bond_data_sub5$yield_change, pch=16, col="blue",
     xlab = "maturity",ylab = "yield_change", xlim = c(0,12))

abline(model_sub5)
```

Which gives me the following graph:

[image: sub_5 model line with offset maturities]

The fact that the maturities have an offset of off_2 is not a problem as when I input my predictions to the function I will create, I will then subtract them by off_2.

The worrying thing is that the 5-year prediction is not at all close to where the actual 5 year should be. Looking at the scatter plot of all maturities we can see this:

```
five_yr_yield <- predict(model_sub5,data.frame(maturity = 5 - off_2))
plot(bond_data$maturity,bond_data$yield_change, pch=16, col="blue",
 xlab = "maturity",ylab = "yield_change", xlim = c(0,12), ylim  = c(-3,0.5))
points(5,five_yr_yield, pch=16, col = "red")
```

Gives:

[image: model_sub5 five year red in red]

The issue with this method is that if I set the model_sub5 5-year prediction as the beginning constraint of model_over5, I will have the exact same problem I am trying to resolve, two constraints in one lm (but this time (5,five_yr_yield) and (10,0) constraints.

Isn't there a way to fit a lm with no slope and zero as an intercept from (2,0) to (10,0) and then apply the segmented function with breakpoints at 3,5 and 7?

If that isn't possible how would I make the logic I am trying to apply work? Or is there another way of doing this?

If anyone has any suggestions I would greatly appreciate them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. At maturity = 2 I want the yield_change to be zero
> 2. At maturity = 10, I
>    want the yield_change to zero
> 3. I want breakpoints(fixed in x) at the 3,
>    5 and 7-year maturity values.

I didn't understand the part with the offsets.

I would just define the sum of squares and minimize it:

```
fun <- function(x, par) {
  y <- x * 0
  y[x > 2] <- par[[1]] * (x[x > 2] - 2) / (3 - 2)
  y[x > 3] <- par[[1]] + (par[[2]] - par[[1]]) / (5 - 3) * (x[x > 3] - 3)
  y[x > 5] <- par[[2]] + (par[[3]] - par[[2]]) / (7 - 5) * (x[x > 5] - 5)
  y[x > 7] <- par[[3]] + (0 - par[[3]]) / (10 - 7) * (x[x > 7] - 7)
  y[x > 10] <- 0
  y
}

yields <- c(-0.131, 0.533, -0.397, -0.429, -0.593, -0.778, -0.92, -0.987, -1.113,       -1.314, -0.808, -1.534, -1.377, -1.459, -1.818, -1.686, -1.73, -1.221, -1.595, -1.568, -1.883, -1.53, -1.64, -1.396, -1.679, -1.782, -1.033, -0.539, -1.207, -1.437, -1.521, -0.691, -0.879, -0.974, -1.816, -1.854, -1.752, -1.61, -0.602, -1.364, -1.303, -1.186, -1.336)
maturities <- c(2.824657534246575, 2.9013698630136986, 3.106849315068493, 3.1534246575342464, 3.235616438356164, 3.358904109589041, 3.610958904109589, 3.654794520547945, 3.778082191780822, 3.824657534246575, 3.9013698630136986, 3.9863013698630136, 4.153424657534247, 4.273972602739726, 4.32054794520548, 4.654794520547945, 4.778082191780822, 4.986301369863014, 5.153424657534247, 5.32054794520548, 5.443835616438356, 5.572602739726028, 5.654794520547945, 5.824425480949174, 5.941911819746988, 6.275245153080321, 6.4063926940639275, 6.655026573845348, 6.863013698630137, 7.191780821917808, 7.32054794520548, 7.572602739726028, 7.693150684931507, 7.901369863013699, 7.986301369863014, 8.32054794520548, 8.654794520547945, 8.986301369863014, 9.068493150684931, 9.32054794520548, 9.654794520547945, 9.903660453626769, 10.155026573845348)

sse <- function(par, x, y) {
  sum((y - fun(x, par))^2)
}

plot(maturities, yields, xlim = c(1, 11))

pars <- optim(c(-1, -1.5, -0.5), sse, x = maturities, y = yields)$par
#[1] -0.4021607 -1.7557449 -1.5516413

curve(fun(x, pars),  col = "dark red", from = 1, to = 11, add = TRUE)
abline(0, 0, lty = 2)
abline(v = 2, lty = 2)
abline(v = 10, lty = 2)
```

[image: resulting plot showing the data and fit]

Comment: Thank you so much this is really helpful! However, if I want to change the condition of having fixed breaks in x (3,5,7) how would I proceed? Can I also use optim to optimise the new break positions in x?  @Roland

Comment: You could try implementing the x positions of the breakpoints as additional parameters. However, starting values will become very important and depending on the data there could easily be issues with the optimization.